# Advisers told him that he did not want - What does "want" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

Does "want" here mean "be in a state of need"?

> In June, during an Oval Office meeting with political advisers and outside consultants, Trump raised the prospect of suing state governments for how they administer elections and said he could not believe they were allowed to change the rules. All the states, he said, should follow the same rules. **Advisers told him that he did not want** the federal government in charge of elections.

> Source: American newspaper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Want" means (as usual) desire.  But the meaning when somebody says "You don't want this" is "If you think about it, you will realise that this is not something you should desire".

Advisers told Trump that, if he considered the consequences, he would realise that putting the federal government in charge of elections is not in his interest.